# Javafx: Reduce events of checkable Listbox

Tags: javafx, checkbox, listbox, coding-style, propertychanged

I have a generic Javafx Listbox with checkable items (up to 20 items).

When I (de-)select an item, a property change is released to update other parts of the program.
It works all fine so far.

But I have additionally 2 buttons to (de-)select all items at once.
Also this working as expected, but I get an event for each item, which means that up to 20 property change events are fired, when one would be enough.

It is not a performance problem, not much is done on the events, but it is bad style.

Can anybody suggest a better solution?

```
    public class FilterBox extends AnchorPane {

        ListView<Item> listFilter;
        Button buttonAll;
        Button buttonNone;

        public FilterBox() {
            init();
            place();
            action();

            getChildren().addAll(listFilter, buttonAll, buttonNone);
            handleChange();
        }

        private void init() {
            listFilter = new ListView<>();

            buttonAll = new Button("All");
            buttonNone = new Button("None");
        }

        private void place() {
            setTopAnchor(listFilter, 0d);
            setBottomAnchor(listFilter, 40d);
            setLeftAnchor(listFilter, 0d);
            setRightAnchor(listFilter, 0d);

            setBottomAnchor(buttonAll, 5d);
            setLeftAnchor(buttonAll, 0d);
            buttonAll.setPrefWidth(75d);

            setBottomAnchor(buttonNone, 5d);
            setRightAnchor(buttonNone, 0d);
            buttonNone.setPrefWidth(75d);
            
        }

        private void action() {
            listFilter.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView((Item item) -> item.selectedProperty()));

            buttonAll.setOnAction((t) -> {
                changeAll(true);
            });

            buttonNone.setOnAction((t) -> {
                changeAll(false);
            });
        }

        private void changeAll(Boolean state) {
            for (Item i : listFilter.getItems()) {
                i.setSelected(state);
            }
        }

        private void setListener(Item item) {
            item.selectedProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
                Trigger.setNewFilterEvent();
            });
        }

        private void handleChange() {
            HashSet<String> list = InputData.getSportList();
            for (String s : list) {
                Item item = new Item(s, true);
                listFilter.getItems().add(item);
                setListener(item);
            }
        }

        public static class Item {

            private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
            private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

            public Item(String name, boolean on) {
                setName(name);
                setSelected(on);
            }

            public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
                return this.name;
            }

            public final String getName() {
                return this.nameProperty().get();
            }

            public final void setName(final String name) {
                this.nameProperty().set(name);
            }

            public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
                return this.selected;
            }

            public final boolean isSelected() {
                return this.selectedProperty().get();
            }

            public final void setSelected(final boolean sel) {
                this.selectedProperty().set(sel);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return getName();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and don't use static scope - __that's__ bad style, not the multiple firing, which you can't prevent anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Trigger.setNewFilterEvent()` is what you want called only once when the "select all" or the "deselect all" actions are fired, then you can use a `boolean` flag for this.

```java
public class FilterBox {

  private boolean ignoreIndividualChanges;
  // other fields omitted for brevity

  private void changeAll(boolean state) {
    ignoreIndividualChanges = true;
    try {
      for (Item i : listFilter.getItems()) {
        i.setSelected(state);
      }
      Trigger.setNewFilterEvent(); // fire one event
    } finally {
      ignoreIndividualChanges = false;
    }
  }

  private void setListener(Item item) {
    item.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
      if (!ignoreIndividualChanges) {
        Trigger.fireNewFilterEvent();
      }
    });
  }

  // other methods omitted for brevity
}
```

Also, note I changed the parameter type for `changeAll` from `Boolean` to `boolean`. There's no reason to use the reference type here, so you should stick with the primitive type.

Comment: question is whether the real issue (if there is any) is important enough to warrant additional logic, paticularly if that involves a boolean flag (which has a nasty smell for me ;).

Comment: Eh. I disagree it's a "smell". As of right now, the OP seems to think the performance benefit would be small or even nonexistent, so the extra effort may not be worth it (though it only took about less than 5 minutes to write without an IDE). But if every `setNewFilterEvent()` triggered a remote call or something, then I would definitely implement the above or some equivalent.

Comment: yeah noses are different ;) But then, seemingly requiring a flag often is smelly on the "other" side - here that would be the api of "Trigger". Can't lnow without details, though

Comment: To me the code smell is performing the `exact same action` no matter which `Item` has changed. The action should at least depend on the `Item` in some way.

Comment: @James_D My assumption is the code is doing something like building a `Predicate` for a `FilteredList`, and so queries _every_ `Item` each time an event is fired (and the other code has a reference to the items somehow; though the `setNewFilterEvent()` method seems to be static, and _that's_ what seems like the biggest smell to me).